# Rule managing in WF

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm beginner in Microsoft Workflow. I did some small project with it and I've got some about it.

Now I've a question: How does workflow manage rules? Has it rule engine? How can we implement rules?

Must I create another application which manage rules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For clarification it might be useful if you explained what you mean by roles.

Comment: I read somewhere which windows workflow has role engine. Is it true? If yes, what does it do and I wonder how it works?

Comment: Ahhhh, you meant Rules not "Roles". WF 3.5 has a Rule engine but it was not carried forward into WF4

Comment: What about WF4.5? Has it "Rule" or Rule Engine? Anyway, I must do it (I mean "Rule") in another project?

Comment: Nope. Not in 4.5 either

Comment: When you are talking about managing rules, there are different aspects of it. Authoring, Building/Composing/Reusing, Versioning, Monitoring, Executing, Revisioning, Deploying, Hosting as Service, Permissions, Packaging... What is your exact definition of managing? WF does allow you to implement rules in a very limited way and combine them in a ruleset/policy. And execute them. Not much of the management functionality comes with WF. If you are interested in execution and management of rules, you need to go for commercial products like [FlexRule](http://www.flexrule.com)

Comment: @ArashAghlara Thank you for leaving a comment. I want first and second ones in the category that you mentioned. I'm not interested in any other right now.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad, from you comment on the question, you are interested in authoring and execution part of business rules. From WF the best you can get is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797584(v=vs.110).aspx which allows you to use RuleSet object (WF 3.5) and Policy4 activity to execute them. The issue with that is it is not a rule approach on how you would really author business rules in any of the standard rule modeling approaches e.g. [Decision Table, Decision model and Notation, Tree and Flow for with rule or decision](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/modeling-business-rule-and-decision/).
IMHO Workflow Foundation (WF) as its name refers to is fine for Workflow, but not in any mean in business rules. Not good at all in managing of them. The other option is using any other business rule management system out there that provides a [decision-as-a-service](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/decision-as-a-service/) capability and then your WF activity can simply call to those.